# How do I write this "if" shorter, as I'm checking the same variable each time?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

```
 if($a === "b" || $a === "c" || $a === "d")
     echo $a;
 else
     echo 'a is not........';
```

Is there a way to write this without repeating `$a` each time?

Answer (score 3):

you're not checking anything. you're doing assignments, since you're using `=` and not `==`.

There's very little you can do to optimize this code. It might be tedious to write out, but in execution terms it's not bad. Don't confuse "shorter" code with "more efficient". e.g

```
if (!in_array($a, array('a', 'b', 'c')) { ... }
```

is less code. But it will almost certainly perform WORSE than your code. Why? Because now you're making PHP create an array on-the-fly. It then has to, internally, loop over that array and compare each value against $a individually, exactly as your "tedious" if() is doing. So all you've done is reduce the amount of code written, but INCREASED execution time because you've added in the entire "create an array" requirement.

Comment: Shouldn't `!` be removed?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: depends on how the actual if() contents are arranged, but yes, it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

I’d be inclined to use a `switch` instead. I find it more readable.

```
switch ($a) {
case 'b':
case 'c':
case 'd':
    echo $a;
    break;
default:
    echo 'a is not........';
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is actually useful in `if elseif else`

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual: [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
if (in_array($a, array("b","c","d"))) {
    echo $a;
} else{
    echo 'a is not........';
}
```